# Inject a class as depency injection in a service

Tags: dependency-injection, symfony-services

I just want to inject a custom module class A as a dependency injection for a custom service. I tried but I failed. Can any one please guide me. I'm using Drupal version 10.

Here is my code.

**moduleb.services.yml**

```
services:
  classb.brokeragency:
    class: Drupal\customb\Services\BrokerAgency
    arguments: [Twn\SoapClient\ClientBuilder]
```

**BrokerAgency.php**

```
<?php 

namespace Drupal\customb\Services;

use \Twn\SoapClient\ClientBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;


class BrokerAgency implements BrokerAgencyInterface {

    protected ClientBuilder $clientBuilder;


    /**
     * @param ClientBuilder $client_builders
     *
     */
    public function __construct(ClientBuilder $client_builder)
    {
        $this->clientBuilder = $client_builder;
    }

    public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
        return new static(
          $client_builder
        );
    }
}
```

But this is giving following error.

[image]

Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

PS - Does Drupal allow this ? If no, then is there any way to achieve. this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I inject a dateFormatter servide inyo a service class named MyService?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/317515/how-do-i-inject-a-dateformatter-servide-inyo-a-service-class-named-myservice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a service/ factory for `Twn\SoapClient\ClientBuilder` to create a new ClientBuilder object and use this service/ factory in your *services.yml*.
To reference a service, you'll need to use the following notation.

```yaml
services:
  classb.brokeragency:
    class: Drupal\customb\Services\BrokerAgency
    arguments: ['@my.client.builder']
```

See [Services and dependency injection in Drupal 8+](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/services-and-dependency-injection/services-and-dependency-injection-in-drupal-8) for more examples and documentation.